# Finding Extrema points of a two variable function with parameters. (And a question about Global minimum).

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

> Let $A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $A>0$, $B^2 <AC$. 
> We define $f(x,y)=Ax^2 +2Bxy+Cy^2+D$. 
> Find local maximum and minimum of $f$. 
> Is there a global minimum of $f$ in the plane?

Note: I am not sure if the "in the plane" was a mistake in the question or not, since we're talking about a function in 3d space, but I wrote it here because it might mean something like finding a minimum on the $x,y$ plane and I'm just not getting it.

**My Attempt:** 
$f_x=2Ax+2By=0 \Longrightarrow 2Ax=-2By \Longrightarrow (A>0) \Longrightarrow x = -\frac{By}{A}$. 
$f_y= 2Cy+2Bx=0$ 
I substituted $x$ into the second equation: 
$2Cy+2B(-\frac{By}{A})=0 \Longrightarrow 2Cy - \frac{2B^2y}{A}=0\Longrightarrow 2y(C-\frac{B^2}{A})=0$. 
Since $AC>B^2$, $C=\frac{B^2}{A}$ is not possible, so I got a point $(0,0)$.
To check if it's a Local Min or Max, I computed the second partial derivatives: 
$f_{xx}=2A$
$f_{yy}=2C$ 
$f_{xy}=2B$ 
Now since $f_{xx}*f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2=4AC-4B^2=4(AC-B^2) > 0 \Longrightarrow $ Then $(0,0)$ is the local minimum of the function. 
Now I'm not sure how to deal with the second part, how do I check if the function has a global minimum or not? 
Any feedback and help is really appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is convex, all local minimum is a global minimum. $(0,0)$ is the global minimum.

We can also prove it by completing the squares.

\begin{align}Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2 +D &= A \left(x+\frac{By}{A} \right)^2+Cy^2-A\left(\frac{By}{A} \right)^2+D \\
&=A \left(x+\frac{By}{A} \right)^2+\left(C-\frac{B^2}{A} \right)y^2+D \\&=A \left(x+\frac{By}{A} \right)^2+\left(\frac{AC-B^2}{A} \right)y^2+D \\
&\ge D\end{align}

Hence $D$ is the lower bound which can only be attained when $y=0$ and $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks, can I say that based on the differentiability of the function and that I have only found one local minimum point then it is a global minimum?  is there anyway to prove that or to show it maybe using algebra for this specific function?

Comment: edited to show a proof based on completing the squares.

Comment: Appreciate the help, I'm not sure, but I noticed that you might have made a mistake when you wrote $(\frac{By}{2A})^2$ instead of $(\frac{By}{A})^2$.

Comment: thanks, that was a mistake.